# Best way to connect database for asp.net mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

I want to know different options available when we are connecting asp.net mvc application to database.

What are pros and cons of each method and what is best method to choose.

In Traditional asp.net web form application i am using DAL approach, which seems to be very useful to me so far even while dealing in shared hosting environment.  I want solution which i can apply in shared hosting environment.

Thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the website [Mikesdotnetting.com](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/About), there is an article titled [ASP.NET MVC is not all about Linq to SQL](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/132/ASP.NET-MVC-is-not-all-about-Linq-to-SQL). Basically what the article talks about is taking a standard ASP.NET web forms n-layered application and moving it into the world of MVC. The only things that are changed are the actual web forms into views. He leaves much of the application as is, the data access layer, the entity objects, the business rules, etc. From reading the article and seeing what you're asking, I think you can easily use what you know (your DAL) and combine that with MVC.

Good luck on your project, and hope this helps some.

Original Web form based application article:

[Building Layered Web Applications with Microsoft ASP.NET 2.0](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/416/building-layered-web-applications-with-microsoft-aspnet-20-part-1)

Answer (score 0):

I use the the following for the data access:

- Entity Framework (Code First)
- Windsor Container for dependency injection set up with the repository pattern to make my controllers testable without having a database.

[Blog post using EF Code First with MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685467)

[Explanation Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)

[Blog post about using MVC3 and Castle Windsor](http://jcreamerlive.com/2011/06/21/dependency-injection-asp-net-mvc-3-castle-windsor/)

Answer (score 0):

There are different Ways to Connect to Databases for ASP.NET MVC web application using ENTITY FRAMEWORK :

- Code-First
- Db-First
- Model-First

Code First approach lets you generate databases and datasets automatically .
Use it if you are developing a large Web application and expecting changes of the Models in Future. So you can alter a database after making changes in the Code Accordingly.

Db-First lets you generate models automatically giving good control over Databases. Make sure there is a Database Admin working in the application.

Model-First Approach is not good option as developer would not be having control over both Model and Database.